# Floating Action Button is not displaying android

Tags: android

This is my layout file.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>



        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/windowBackground"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottomButtons"
            >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/cart"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:elevation="6dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.wokoshop.sony.app.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In this layout Floating action button is not displaying.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: -1 because you did that in wrong way and you didn't even search about it in docs or even in this best website! interesting with this reputation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view pager is being set to wrap_content and in this case the rest of the view is what its saying it needs to contain its content.  If you change the root viewgroup to Relative layout your problems are solved.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#456786"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="#456786"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:background="#765876"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using a `LinearLayout` as the container for your main layout.

Replace it with a `RelativeLayout` and the `FAB` will show up.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put a FAB (Floating Action Button) in a `LinearLayout`. There's  a special layout in the Android Design Support Library called the `CoordinatorLayout`, which correctly handles Snackbars and FABs. 
Here are two nice tutorials which show you how it can be used:

https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/
https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons

Your layout is quite complicated, so you should play a bit with it to figure it out where the FAB and the content fragment will be in your structure. Probably your `ViewPager` and FAB will be inside the `CoordinatorLayout`.